# Handle failed bamboo plans

Tags: build, continuous-integration, bamboo

Is there any way to handle failed bamboo plans? I need to invoke few REST API's if build plan fails by invoking other plans/stages or send some custom notifications based on conditions. Is this possible?

From bamboo documentation, I could find that there are triggers for successful builds but not for the failed builds.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Pre-Post Build Command Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.sysbliss.bamboo.plugins.prepost-build-command/server/overview) plugin. It has an option to run a command after build fails.

Comment: Hi Frennky, thank you for the response. Looks like the plugin mentioned above is only for Bamboo server but we are using Bamboo cloud. I am looking at Final Stage in Bamboo but it should invoke REST API's only if previous stages failed. Is there any way to obtain the previous stage result?